# Load page with redirect timer, forward request to trigger a workflow with Zapier, redirect to URL with variable

Tags: javascript, html, url, redirect, zapier

I'm an HTML n00b, and while I can figure out some of the formatting stuff, the scripting side eludes me.

I'm trying to figure out a way to make this happen:

Step 1. A user clicks a link, and is brought to a webpage with a redirect timer (say 10 seconds).

Step 2. Behind the scenes during those 10 seconds, I need to make a URL request with a query string (I'm using a URL to trigger a webhook workflow with Zapier) which the user doesn't see.

Step 3. After 10 seconds, redirect user to www.site.com/example
where "example" is concatenated from a variable in the query string from step 2.
Phew! Thoughts?